# Trouble finding api's to searching a Song in Google play music ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to integrate google play music in my application, in which i need to search a song in google play music and need to redirect the user to the google play music with the song i entered for searching

i have tried using this Link :[searched Song with URL](https://play.google.com/store/search?c=music&docType=4&q=dirty%20dancers)
But i need the song id which i can use for redirecting the user to particular song.
I have also tried the [UnOfficial Google Music Search](https://github.com/simon-weber/gmusicapi) Api's But i don't need those api's and i haven't found the desired results.

Comment: My suggestion is using spotify's api, I have some friends that have made playlist making apps and stuff with their api, you can practically recreate the spotify app with it, if you are forced to use google play music, god help you

Comment: Yes i have also integrated Spotify in this.. and also i need Google Play music. if any one can help me figure out this issue.. ?

Comment: @Cqlsys did you got any solution for google music play API ?